# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'permissions')

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make an automod, which only moderates users who don't have the admin permission, but for some reason keep getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'permissions')". Here's my code:

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < bannedWords.length; i++) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(bannedWords[i])) {
            bannedWordEmbed = {
                title : "That word is not allowed here!",
                color : embedColor,
                author : {
                    name : message.author.username,
                    icon_url : message.author.displayAvatarURL()
                }
            }
            message.delete();
            message.author.send({embeds : [bannedWordEmbed]});
            logToStaff(message);
            return;
        }
     }
    }
})
```

Comment: It means `message.member` is `null`. Are you trying to send a message as a DM?

Comment: Can you send the full traceback?